# Reload page when radiobutton is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to order objects from a database using radiobuttons. I would like to pass the ordering arguments through the url, and then reload the page when a radiobutton is pressed. However I am having trouble with reloading the page when the radiobutton is checked.

The radiobuttons have a class, and in JS I am accessing them and adding event listeners to every single one. The problem is, the reload either works but never stops reloading, or the page doesn't reload at all.

Relevant JS code

```
const url = (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams;

let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('sf');

for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', window.location.reload(false));
}
```

This particular code infinitely reloads the page.

Other things I have tried:

instead of `click` i used `change` and `RadioStateChange`, this yields the same result

instead of adding `window.location.reload(false)`, i tried making a
function `clickedRadio`:

```
function clickedRadio(radio){
    if(radio.checked)
        window.location.reload(false);
}
```

this code doesn't do anything.

I am pretty sure the page infinitely reloads because I am assigning event listeners in a loop, but how else would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.addEventListener` expects a callback function as its second parameter which it can execute when your button is clicked. At the moment you are not adding a callback function, but rather you are executing a function (and thus the return result of `window.location.reload(false)` is being used instead).

So, you're actually calling your callback function when the page loads, not when the click event occurs.

Instead, a relatively simple solution would be to wrap the function you want to execute in a function itself. This way you will be able to call your function which then executes the page reload.

```
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', _ => window.location.reload(false));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', window.location.reload(false));
```

Isn't tying the function to the event, it's actually calling `window.location.reload(false)`.

You should define a function that calls `reload`, like this

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => window.location.reload(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', window.location.reload(false));
```

This will execute `.reload()` *immediately* and (if the page wasn't reloading, making it moot anyway) bind the *result* of that function (which is undefined) as the event listener.

You don't want to bind to the result of reloading, you want to bind to a function that reloads:

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location.reload(false);
});
```

Now, whether or not this will fix your table sorting, that itself is a bit out of scope here.  But this should prevent the infinite reloading and at least bind the reload to the click event.